# list object has no attribute split error for csv file

Tags: python

Please help me understand what is wrong with my code, I simply can't figure it out

```
with open("floo.csv", 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=",")
    with open('departments_upd.csv','w',newline='') as csvout:
        writer = csv.writer(csvout)
        for row in reader:
            df = row.split(".")
            bleep = df[1] + '.' + df[0] + '.' + df[2]
            writer.writerow(row)
return bleep
```

Comment: Have you done debug printing to see what you get at each step?  `csv.reader` already returns you a list.  It's DOING the split.  You don't have to.  Also remember that `bleep` will only contain the result from the final row.  You're overwriting it each time.

Comment: Why are you splitting on `"."` if your delimiter is `","`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of the 'row' variable? Basically, it is saying that you can not use the 'split' method on a variable of type 'list'. If it is a list of index 1, you could just convert it to a string and then use the split method by adding a line:

`row_str = row[0]`

and then using the split method

Answer (score -1):

use pandas:
example:

```
covid_training_data = pd.read_csv("covidTrain.csv")
```

I am kind of curious what this project is tbh

Comment: OP has not indicated that they are using or are able to use Pandas.